# Converting Wrapper<Derived> to Wrapper<Base>

Tags: c#, generics

I have code like this:

```
class Base { }

class Derived : Base { }

class Wrapper<T> {

    public T Value { get; }

    public Wrapper (T value) { Value = value; }
}
```

I would like to use `Wrapper` like this:

```
Wrapper<Base> wrapper = new Wrapper<Derived> (new Derived ());
```

But it ends up with this error:

> Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Wrapper<Derived>' to 'Wrapper<Base>'

I tried creating method in `Wrapper` `class` that would act as converter

```
public Wrapper<TResult> To<TResult> () /* Constraints needed here. */ =>
    new Wrapper<TResult> (Value);
```

But I'm missing some valid constraints. Current code ends up with error:

> S1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'TResult'

I would imagine constraints on `To` method could look like `where T : TResult`, but that's not valid constraints.

Any ways to implement converter from `Wrapper<Derived>` to `Wrapper<Base>` easily?

Comment: Have you tried `Wrapper<Base> wrapper = new Wrapper<Base> (new Derived ());`?

Comment: That would work in case wher you are creating object in advance, but in cases where it looks like this: `var wrapper = new Wrapper<Derived> (new Derived ()); /* Some other code/ */ var newWrapper = wrapper;` it won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use covariance like so:

```
class Base { }

class Derived : Base { }

interface IWrapper<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

class Wrapper<T> : IWrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public Wrapper(T value) { Value = value; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWrapper<Base> wrapper = new Wrapper<Derived>(new Derived());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go. Of course, I would like to avoid introducing new `interface`, but if there will be no other suggestions I'll go this way.

Comment: unfortunately covariance and contravariance work only with interfaces and delegates, so you'll have to use the interface approach if you want to use this method.

Comment: Yes, already tried covariance on `class`, but that didn't work.

Comment: And what should I do if `Wrapper` is `struct` and not `class`?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, it should work the same way. Just call the default ctor from your ctor like this: public Wrapper(T value) : this() { Value = value; }

Answer (score 3):

At first I would add a constraint to the class demanding that `T` must be of type `Base`:

```
class Base { }
class Derived : Base { }

class Wrapper<T> where T : Base // T must be (derived from) Base
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public Wrapper (T value) { Value = value; }
}
```

Secondly, a generic converter would be **dangerous**. What if someone tries to convert a `Wrapper<Gnu>` to a `Wrapper<Lion>`?

So I'd take a step back and make a non-generic converter that simply converts to `Wrapper<Base>`:

```
public Wrapper<Base> ToBase()
{
     return new Wrapper<Base>(Value);    
}
```

And this works because of the constraint for `T` at class level.

---

C# is actually a language known for a high level of type safety. But you can get around it and do what you asked for in the comment by ommitting any constraints and just trying to cast whatever comes in:

```
public Wrapper<TResult> To<TResult>() where TResult : class
{
     return new Wrapper<TResult>(Value as TResult);    
}
```

You need the `class` constraint and the `as` operator because a direct cast between two generic parameters is not compilable (as the IL depends too much on the specific types).

But this will return `Wrapper` instances with `Value` set to `null` if the types don't match. And it will work with derived types instead of base types too. So take care. You may add some extra checks for that. And take care of the gnus :)

---

UPDATE:

A safer way:

```
public Wrapper<TResult> To<TResult>() where TResult : class// TResult must also be (derived from) Base
{
    if (!typeof(TResult).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    return new Wrapper<TResult>(Value as TResult);
}
```

This checks that `T` is derived from `TResult` and throws an `InvalidCastException` if not. You may refine that for your needs.

Comment: And if I want `Wrapper` to stay generic and be able to take any type? I would like to convert from `Wrapper<AnyDerived>` to `Wrapper<AnyBase>`.

Comment: As you pointed with aditional comment that would require some type checking before using `as`.

Comment: @DovydasSopa added a version with a little check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that the generic types `Wrapper<Base>` and `Wrapper<Derived>` are two completely different classes for the .NET Framework

What you could do is creating a new `Wrapper` of type `Base`:

```
Wrapper<Base> wrapper = new Wrapper<Base>(new Derived());
```

Or to complete your To-method approach:

```
public Wrapper<TResult> To<TResult>() where TResult : T 
    => new Wrapper<TResult>( (TResult)Value ); // This could throw an error

public bool TryCastTo<TResult>(out Wrapper<TResult> derivedWrapper) where TResult : T
{
    derivedWrapper = null;

    // EDIT: changed to the version from René Vogt since this is much cleaner and mine had a little error
    if (!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TResult)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    derivedWrapper = new Wrapper<TResult>( (TResult)Value );
    return true;
}
```

The usage would be:

```
Wrapper<Derived> derivedWrapper1 = wrapper.To<Derived>();
Wrapper<Derived> derivedWrapper2;
bool success = wrapper.TryCastTo<Derived>(out derivedWrapper2);
```